# unable to edit CSS styles in chrome devtools

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools, sizzle

I have javascript code the runs every 400ms and checks if a certain element is found on the page.

To search the element we use JQuery find and provide the html element as context.

```
$('html').find('#findMe')
```

Because we are using find with a context JQuery sizzle adds an id attribute to the html element which in turn cause the css editor to refresh not giving me enough time to make any changes.
Because we run this every 400ms, it is impossible to edit the CSS.

I am wondering if there is a way to resolve this maybe a setting in chrome.

UPDATE: here is the relevant code from Sizzle, as appears in jQuery 1.6.4 -

```
            // qSA works strangely on Element-rooted queries
            // We can work around this by specifying an extra ID on the root
            // and working up from there (Thanks to Andrew Dupont for the technique)
            // IE 8 doesn't work on object elements
            } else if ( context.nodeType === 1 && context.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "object" ) {
                var oldContext = context,
                    old = context.getAttribute( "id" ),
                    nid = old || id,
                    hasParent = context.parentNode,
                    relativeHierarchySelector = /^\s*[+~]/.test( query );

                if ( !old ) {
                    context.setAttribute( "id", nid );
                } else {
                    nid = nid.replace( /'/g, "\\$&" );
                }
                if ( relativeHierarchySelector && hasParent ) {
                    context = context.parentNode;
                }

                try {
                    if ( !relativeHierarchySelector || hasParent ) {
                        return makeArray( context.querySelectorAll( "[id='" + nid + "'] " + query ), extra );
                    }

                } catch(pseudoError) {
                } finally {
                    if ( !old ) {
                        oldContext.removeAttribute( "id" );
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Uhm, no! Sizzle does not add an ID to any element at all, and the selector makes no sense, as ID's are unique, and you could just do `$('#findMe').length` to see if the element exists. Also, why not just stop that silly script if it's preventing you from doing whatever it is you're doing ?

Comment: @adeneo - Sizzle does (or at least did) add an id temporarily in some cases. See https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js  lines 4939-4969

Answer (score 1):

### Stylebot: devtools alternative

As an immediate solution, I'd recommend giving "Stylebot" chrome extension a try. It's an alternative to Chrome Devtools (which you're having trouble with) and allows you to override CSS on the page. Plus it let's you save the CSS so you can refresh the page and keep working with the same styles as you iterate and improve your code.

### **Additionally, regarding your Sizzle problem:**

By default, Sizzle doesn't add an ID to any elements. Though perhaps you mean that you have as script rewriting the ID attributes of the found element?

I would suggest taking another look at your script and seeing if there is a better way to accomplish your goal. Ideally without a timeout. Perhaps run it once on page load. Or create a function and attach it to specific events that would generate new elements and thus require you to run a find function.